# Returning anonymous struct from template function (for structured binding)

Tags: c++, c++17

I wanted to use new C++17 features and wanted to use a structured binding to return multiple values from a (template) function. I can get it to work, but I want it to work *better*.
A simplified version of the code is  (the real code is larger and have better variable names):

```
template <class O>
struct {
  int a;
  double b;
} F(int i,O o) {
   return {i, o(i)};
}
void foo(int i) {
   auto [a,b]=F(i, [=](int k)->double {return 1.0/k; /*...*/});
   // ...
};
```

The combination of anonymous struct and template function didn't work in VS 2019, so I had to write:

```
struct Dummy {
  int a;
  double b;
};
template <class O>
Dummy F(int i,O o) {
   return {i, o(i)};
}
void foo(int i) {
   auto [a,b]=F(i, [=](int k)->double {return 1.0/k; /*...*/});
   // ...
};
```

or:

```
template <class O>
std::tuple<int,double> F(int i,O o) {
   return {i, o(i)};
}
void foo(int i) {
   auto [a,b]=F(i, [=](int k)->double {return 1.0/k; /*...*/});
   // ...
};
```

Preference:

- I don't *need* the return-type struct, and thus I prefer the anonymous variant,
  and I know that it works for non-template functions.
- I want the member-names in the struct for documentation purposes, and thus I find the tuple-variant less clear. (This an especially an issue with more members of the same type.)

So, what is the best way to handle this also for template functions?

The error messages were:

- error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'identifier'
- error C2332: 'struct': missing tag name
- error C3306: '': > unnamed class template is not allowed

Comment: Best way is to used a named class. Giving a name is an opportunity to make the code more understandable.

Comment: *"I know that it works for non-template functions."* Rejected by gcc/clang though [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PqqczjYjE)

Comment: @eerorika normally I agree, but in this case it was due to refactoring splitting a function in half, so there's no obvious name for it.

Comment: @HansOlsson Just because there isn't a name for it yet, doesn't mean that a new name couldn't be given to it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about local struct:

```cpp
template <class O>
auto F(int i, O o) {
    struct {
        int a;
        double b;
    } res {i, o(i)}; 
   return res;
}
void foo(int i) {
   auto [a,b] = F(i, [=](int k)->double {return 1.0/k; /*...*/});
   // ...
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cY5xT4eMG)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `std::tuple` (or `std::pair` in this case). E.g.

```cpp
#include<tuple>

template <class O>
auto F(int i,O o) {
   return std::tuple{i, o(i)};
}
void foo(int i) {
   auto [a,b]=F(i, [=](int k)->double {return 1.0/k; /*...*/});
   // ...
};
```